# Volume of a paperweight

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

> A paperweight has a slanted top described by x + y + z = 2. Its edges
>   are orthogonal to the $xy$–plane, and the bottom of the paperweight is formed by the
>   triangle with vertices $(1, 0, 0)$, $(0, −1, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 0)$. Use a triple integral to find the volume of the paperweight.

From the base of the graph I got 
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{y+1}^{-y+1} \;dx\;dy $$

After taking into account the slanted top I get

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{y+1}^{-y+1}\int_{0}^{2-y-x} \;dz \;dx\;dy $$

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look right to me. Here's what I'm getting:

$(\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{0}\int_{0}^{y+1}\int_{0}^{2-y-x}dzdxdy) + (\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{-y+1}\int_{0}^{2-y-x}dzdxdy)$

or:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x-1}^{-x+1}\int_0^{2-y-x}dzdydx$

Say we start with y as the outer integral. Pick a y-value. Then along the cross section go from the left most boundary to the right boundary to get the x boundaries. The left most boundary is the y-axis ie: x=0. No problem there. But the right boundary is represented by two different lines hence two different functions. We can't have two functions as the limit in the integral. So we need to split the integral.

But starting with x as the outer integral avoids this problem

Comment: looks like you split $$ \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{y+1}^{-y+1} \;dx\;dy $$ in to two parts. any reason why the component of thetriangle below the x axis is not included? Could you explain how you got it please?

Comment: Below the x-axis... the bounds of the object goes from 0 to y+1 ( the line is y=x-1 so x=y+1), along the x-axis. But above the x-axis, the object goes from 0 to -y+1 (the line is y=-x+1 so x = -y+1). So the behavior is different below the x-axis vs above.

Comment: Look at the triangle cross section in the x-y plane, pick a y-value. go from the left to the right along that horizontal line at y. You see that x goes to a different boundary line below the x-axis as opposed to above.